# How postman getting JSON response value by iteration from a list

Tags: postman

I have following JSON response, and in the test, I created a list of the key I will like to log/capture. But output returns **error: TypeError: responseData.get is not a function** because reads in as string when interpreting "responseData.i".

```
JSON response:
{
"Id": 1287,
"LastName": "Trump",
"FirstName": "Donald",
"MiddleName": "Von",
"City": "New York City",
"Phone": "66 77 88",
"State": "New York",
"Fax": "111-222-333",
"ReferenceId": "12345",
"Active": false,
"CurrentWorkingSchemeId": null
}

var responseData = pm.response.json()
var list_data = \["Id", "Fax", "Active"\];
for (i of list_data) {
console.log(responseData.Id, responseData.Fax, responseData.Active);
console.log(i, responseData.i);
console.log(i, responseData.get(i));
}
```

what do I need to do so:
responseData.i = responseData.Id
NOT
responseData.i = responseData."Id"

Thanks

Comment: Does `var list_data = \["Id", "Fax", "Active"\];` actually pass muster on planet JavaScript? Are the backslash characters intended?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax would be `console.log(i, responseData[i]);`